# How to avoid memory leak at flask web-app?

Tags: python, flask, neural-network, uwsgi, ram

I have the server on Ubuntu 18 in digitalocean is deployed on the flask + nginx + uwsgi. 4 cores 8 Gb RAM. The image is loaded through the form and processed by the neural network script **detect.py** . The operation requires a large amount of RAM in the process of execution (about 2 Gb). After each iteration of the script, the memory is reduced. So far after 5-6 executed, the server goes down with an error due to lack of memory. Log RAM consumption such (the first entry after the restart and further after each iteration):

[image]

Uwsgi process status and process memory consumption:

[image]

From the beginning, I thought I had configured the uwsgi server incorrectly. I tried to add / change various parameters, but it did not help. Then I checked the work on the local computer on the built-in flask server. And the problem with memory is the same!

The most interesting thing is that if execute an image processing script directly from the command line, there is no problem. A memory leak appears only when you call the **detect.py** function through the server.

Flask endpoint:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('NO selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if not allowed_file(file.filename):
            flash("Only JPG file is used")
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            img = (os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            count = detect(images=img)
            return redirect(url_for("result", count=count))
            #return str(count)
    return render_template("index.html")
```

And now I'm confused, what to do next?
And the second, perhaps there is a setting in uwsgi that will help free up memory without restarting the server?

Comment: Hey, I have a similar issue. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @zwlayer I'm using task queue for each view https://python-rq.org/   After each task, the memory is released

Comment: Thanks for reply. If possible could you give more deailts ? (Maybe with an edit in your question to show how can it be applied in this case?)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any code. The main point is not to call your function directly, but to pass it as an argument to the queue, and the RQ module will make the whole memory release routine

Comment: Is it mean, you're giving your index function (in your question above) to a queue as an argument ? Is this like a single line change in your code? In the doc you pointed earlier, i saw these two lines : `q = Queue(connection=Redis())`  and `result = q.enqueue(count_words_at_url, 'http://nvie.com')`  So, in your case (I'm referring to the code in your question again), are you supposed to do something like  `q = Queue(connection=Redis())` and `result = q.enqueue(index,)` ? Sorry if it is silly I don't know anything about Redic or rq module.

Comment: You need to put in queue function which running NN. In my case this is function  `detect` with argument img. I call this function at the end of the function `index` . Queue job looks like   `count = q.enqueue(detect, img)`

Comment: Thanks alot for the additional information. One more (and hopefully final) question: Where do you create Queue instance ? (I mean `redis_conn = Redis() q = Queue(connection=redis_conn)`) It is on server side like somewhere just before app.run() line of flask ? Like:  `  if __name__ == "__main__":  redis_conn = Redis() q = Queue(connection=redis_conn) app.run() ` ?

Comment: It depends on the structure of your project. Usually there is a file app.py in which the instance  `app = Flask(__name__)`is called. In this file you can add the queue definition ` q = Queue(connection=Redis())` and import it into any other file, or define it directly in the file where the queue is called. In general, there is no common rule here, depending on the project structure. I would recommend you to try to do something and ask a new question about queue usage in case of errors.